# Android webview can not load web pages

Tags: android, webview

I can not load web pages using webview,Nothing is displayed，
this url "http://dev.51yunche.com:7000/WeChat/Service%20introduce.html",
this is my webview

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.drive_web);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);//DOM Storage
        webView.loadUrl("http://dev.51yunche.com:7000/WeChat/Service%20introduce.html");
```

this xml:

```
 <WebView
            android:id="@+id/drive_web"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
```

The console does not have any prompts or error messages。I'd like to hear some input from more experienced WebView users (and developers?).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The Url link opens a blank page, that why nothing is shown

Answer (score 1):

This is not webview Issue.In web browser also that url display Nothing.check that Backend or design code of your html file.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space encoded character `%20` in your URL...

use a valid url like:

```
 webView.loadUrl("http://dev.51yunche.com:7000/WeChat/Serviceintroduce.html");
```

Alternatively you can also try `URLEncoder.encode(YOUR_URL);` function to encode the Url

Answer (score 0):

Your link itself doesn't display anything in web browser. If you still have any doubt, just simply create a normal html page by yourself and run it from your local system and check it out.